# HTML Video - Actions OnEnd not Working

Tags: javascript, html, function, video, html5-video

I am having trouble getting the `onended` function to work with my HTML video. It doesnt have to be `onended` but basically I want a series of things to happen when the video has ended.

Code is as follows:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
window.onload = playVideo;
function playVideo() 
{
    var video = document.getElementById("video");
    var message = document.getElementById("videoinfo");
    var button = document.getElementById("playpause");
    button.onclick = function()
    {
        if (video.paused)
        {
            video.play();
            button.innerHTML = "Pause";
            message.value = "The video is playing, click the Pause button to pause the video.";
        }
        else
        {
            video.pause();
            button.inerHTML = "Play";
            message.value = "The video is paused, click the Play button to play the video.";
        }
        video.onended = function(e)
        {
            button.innerHTML = "Play";
            message.value = "The video has ended, click Play to restart the video."
        }    
    }
}
</script>

<button type="button" id="playpause" onclick="playVideo()">Play</button> 
<br> 
<video id="video" width="320" height="240">
    <source src="Video/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="Video/movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
<br />
<textarea id="videoinfo" cols="90">
Click the Play button to start the video.
</textarea>
```

Thanks for the help

EDIT: I cannot post my own answer for 8 hours with 10 or less reputation, so I have to edit:

After 2 days of trying to get this to work, I post a question on here so I can figure it out. Less than 10 mins later I manage to get it to work.

I used an `onEnded` function in the `<video>` tag and linked that to a javascript function called `videoEnded()`.

See below:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function playVideo() 
{
    var video = document.getElementById("video");
    var message = document.getElementById("videoinfo");
    var button = document.getElementById("playpause");
    button.onclick = function()
    {
        if (video.paused)
        {
        video.play();
        button.innerHTML = "Pause";
        message.value = "The video is playing, click the Pause button to pause the video.";
        }
        else
        {
            video.pause();
            button.inerHTML = "Play";
            message.value = "The video is paused, click the Play button to play the video.";
        }
    }
}
function videoEnded()
{
    var message = document.getElementById("videoinfo");
    var button = document.getElementById("playpause");
    button.innerHTML = "Play";
    message.value = "The video has ended, click Play to restart the video.";
}
</script>
```

Hope this can help someone else out. I have searched for days looking for an answer and nothing would work.

Thanks

Comment: You're adding the ended handler in the button click handler, so the button has to be clicked first before the handler is attached.

Comment: For what I see function videoEnded never gets called, I think you need to add the line I just wrote to you bellow before the button.onclick.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Video.ended)

 // Code when video ends.
```

EDIT: sorry for don't give any other explanation, but, have you tried by using .addEventListener method instead? and in which Browser do you develop / debug?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, I have tried using `.addEventListner` but couldnt get anything to fire. I finaly figured it out, by using the `onEnded` function in the `<video>` tag. Check my edit out above. I couldnt answer my own question due to reputation being under 10.